# Why is the token in my custom module not replaced?

Tags: 8, tokens

I want to use the token `[user:name]` in my module. This module contains a sample  ControllerBase class

In my class I test this:

```
class Page_test_Controller extends ControllerBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function token() {
        $build = array(
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => t('[user:name] hello'),
        );
        return $build;
    }

}
```

When I load my page the token isn't replaced as shown here:

[image]

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translatable strings don't use tokens, but placeholders, see for example https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21FormattableMarkup.php/function/FormattableMarkup%3A%3AplaceholderFormat/8 for some documentation, or https://www.drupal.org/node/322729 (more 7.x, but conceptually still mostly OK).

Tokens are when you have user configurable text like the user register/confirmation mails. It doesn't make sense to have token in a text that is hardcoded since tokens are only useful if that text can be customized by the user. For documentation on how to use the token API, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21Token.php/class/Token/8